# memory barrier intrinsics for ARM (analogous to _mm_*fence())

Tags: gcc, arm, sse, intrinsics, sse2

I'm looking for the ARM analogue for the Intel memory barrier intrinsics `_mm_lfence(), _mm_sfence(), _mm_mfence()` introduced together with SSE/SSE2.

I'm using gcc (4.8), but the solution should be portable to other compilers (icc, clang).

From this ARM document

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14552.html

I concluded I'd need intrinsics such as `__dmb()` and `__schedule_barrier()`, but according to this site

https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/258449

these intrinsics are not available on gcc.

I'm not sure about the CMSIS library mentioned there, would this provide a portable solution?

I also thought of mapping the 3 fence intrinsics to `__sync_synchronize()` (full memory barrier), but I'm not sure about the portability of this intrinsic either (and there is no version for read or write barriers, only this full barrier).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your gcc supports C11 atomics (4.9 and later, AFAIK), you can use `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order)`. If you have an older gcc, the `__atomic`-builtin `__atomic_thread_fence (int)` may be available.

Comment: @EOF: Thanks. I want to avoid C11 for the time being, so I'd go for the other intrinsics. I'm just not sure whether read barriers or write barriers can be mapped onto the different memory orders. AFAIK, I could only use `__atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` which would be mapped onto something like full barriers [(see e.g. here)](https://www.think-cell.com/en/career/talks/pdf/think-cell_talk_memorymodel.pdf). Moreover, on closer inspection, there may not even exist an equivalent for read and write barriers in the ARM instruction set.

Comment: There *are* write barriers in ARM: `dmb st` (`st` for `store`), however there are indeed no pure read barriers. Unfortunately the C11-type barriers are acquire/release-type, rather than read/write barriers, but I'd expect somebody who is worried about such minuscule details to also be able to write the trivial bit of inline-assembly to implement a write-barrier for ARM themselves.

Comment: I'd recommend C11 atomics with a newer gcc.  If you don't already have a codebase that uses different atomic primitives / threading, it's definitely the way to go for new code.  Since AArch64 has load-acquire and store-release instructions, you can get more efficient code from using those instead of plain loads and separate store-barriers.  C11/C++11 atomics seem like a good way to do things that the compiler can actually understand and optimize as much as possible while preserving correctness.

Comment: @EOF, @artless noise, @Peter Cordes: Maybe some explanation on my motivation: I'm working on a template-based C++ wrapper library for SIMD vector intrinsics. I startet with SSE/AVX (Intel), so the NEON (ARM) wrappers kind of emulate SSE behavior. That's why I'm looking for a way to implement these three barriers (since Intel has them) and can't really use atomics. (Actually any user of C++11 would be free to use atomics on top of my wrapper library.) Maybe I should go for `__sync_synchronize()` for all three barriers?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc007826/Barrier_Litmus_Tests_and_Cookbook_A08.pdf  You may ID the CPU (maybe USER provides function) and have different barriers depending on the result.  Also, you can just make the barriers macros which the user needs to fill in (or both ID and macros).  You want to be *portable*, but you are using `_mm_lfence()`?  I think you want to isolated the non-portable aspects.  Also: https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2011/03/22/memory-access-ordering--an-introduction

Comment: @artlessnoise: Very helpful links, thank you! On the idea behind portability: I'm hiding fence instructions and SIMD vector instructions in template wrapper functions, so the same high-level code should compile on SSE, AVX, NEON etc. So e.g. `lfence()` hides either `_mm_lfence()` or the NEON equivalent (which I still have to figure out).